# How to waterproof this porch area over my crawlspace?

Tags: deck, waterproofing, water-damage, crawlspace, porch

This area seems like a bad design - essentially a piece of flat roof next to the house...

[image]

The previous roof/porch here didn't seem to have any slope, and all the water drained towards the house (to the left of the door) and rotted out most of the support (luckily the house didn't sag too much).

It was previously 3/4 ply with some kind of anti-slip coating with metal flashing, I've bought some 3/4 Pressure Treated ply and butyl flashing tape - but not sure where to go from here?

I'm planning on adding at least 1/4" per foot slope out to the left away from the house.

What kind of coating should I use on the PT Plywood?

Thank you!

Comment: I would slope down to the far corner from both directions. If the flashing is exposed to potential abrasion (or UV light, probably), then metal flashing is a must. You've got a problem, then, with corrosion from the pressure treated plywood. I think standard practice is to use rubber flashing to isolate metal flashing from the pressure treatment's copper.

Comment: It needs a roof. I might find a tile with lots of surface texture and follow a TCNA Handbook detail for wet locations (RedGard/AquaDefense). It would require stiffer stairs than I've learned to expect, but otherwise the pattern seems relatively safe. I hate the crawl space under there. No roof? Should have stopped at the wall edges.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is far too many questions in one. While they all relate to your project, they're really unrelated. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit] to focus on one thing at a time. Feel free to click the "ask question" more than once to get them all covered.

Comment: Sorry about that @FreeMan. I'll edit my main question.

Comment: Thank you @popham. It's a terrible design in my opinion. There is no roof over this area, just the 1ft overhang from the eaves.

Are you suggesting building a roof structure over the whole thing, or creating a low-slope roof to form the porch?

Comment: A roof way up above would be best, but budgets are a thing. Tiling seems like the next best long term solution. I could see using a roof membrane below deck boards instead if the elevation wasn't already so constrained, but I think I would still prefer the tile. Keeping things pretty with the eventual stairs is my one reservation. (Any roof material won't be designed for the traffic density on the porch versus a roof.)

Comment: Thanks so much @popham - I'll look into the roof membrane and tile option.